# Transform equation to Helmholtz equation by variable substitution

Tags: acoustics

I'm currently working on an acoustic propagation project where I need to transform the following equation

$$ \phi_{xx} + 2m \phi_x + k^2 \phi = 0$$

to a classic Helmholtz equation

$$\psi_{xx} + \kappa^2 \psi = 0  $$

by variable substitution. I tried to do that with

$$ \phi(x) = y(u) $$ 
$$ \phi_x(x) = u'y'(u) $$
$$ \cdots $$

and injecting it in the initial equation and I obtained

$$ 4m^2u^2y_{uu} + k^2 y = 0$$

where

$$ u = \exp{(-2mx)}/m $$

by forcing the multiplying factor of $y'(u)$ to be nil after injecting in the initial equation.

I have no idea how to to find a substitution leading to a genuine helmholtz equation.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Why do that? The original equation is solvable as it is. In any case this really belongs in Math.

Comment: Or is $\phi=f(x,t)$?

Comment: MIght [math.se] be better suited for this question?

Answer (score 0):

$$ \phi_{xx} + 2m \phi_x + k^2 \phi = 0= ( (\partial +m)^2 -m^2 +k^2) \phi,$$ 
so, completion of the square immediately suggests
$$
e^{mx}(\partial +m) \phi=\partial \psi,
$$
that is,
$$
\psi= e^{mx} \phi.
$$

Consequently, 
$$
\psi_{xx}= e^{mx} (\partial +m)^2 \phi =e^{mx}  (m^2-k^2)\phi,
$$
from your original equation, so that 
$$\psi_{xx} +  (k^2-m^2)  \psi = 0 . $$

This is a one-liner, but I provided the intermediate steps for pedagogy.

Comment: Can you clarify a little? $\psi=e^{mx}\phi$ doesn't solve the eqn in the second line. Maybe it's easier to write the operator $\partial +m$ as $e^{-mx}\partial e^{mx}$ so that $(\partial +m)^2 = e^{-mx} \partial^2 e^{mx}$ and plugging into your first line motivates your useful definition of $\psi$.

Comment: @Alex Thanks, it was a silly typo.

Answer (score 0):

As Gert pointed out, the original equation is solvable, there is no need to substitute to solve it. Anyway the approach is educational.

$$\phi_xx+2m\phi_x+k^2\phi = 0$$

is an exponential horn propagation equation for the velocity potential $\phi$. The full version of the equation reads

$$\frac{\partial{}^2\phi}{\partial{}x^2}+\frac{\mathrm{d}S}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{\partial{}\phi}{\partial{}x}+k^2\phi=0$$

where is the case of an exponential horn, $S$ is given by $\mathrm{e}^{2mx}$. You can use math as in [Cosmas's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/513164/247315) or you can use *Webster's equation*

$$\frac{\partial{}^2}{\partial{}x^2}(\phi\sqrt{S})+\left(k^2-H(x)\right)\phi\sqrt{S}=0, \quad H(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{S}}\frac{\mathrm{d}^2\sqrt{S}}{\mathrm{d}x^2}$$

which is directly giving you the substitution $\psi(x)=(\phi\sqrt{S})(x)=\phi(x)\mathrm{e}^{mx}$. The latter equation is completely equivalent to the first one and is often used to simplify to an ordinary Helmholtz equation.

Please note that in the frequential domain, all the above equations can be written for the pressure or the velocity potential.